# Selecting rows of a dataframe according to the correspondence of two covariates' levels

Tags: r, subset

I am currently working on two different dataframes, one of which is extremely long (`long`). What I need to do is to select all the rows of `long` whose corresponding `id_type` appears at least once in the other (smaller) dataset.

Suppose the two dataframes are:

```
long <- read.table(text = "
  id_type   x1   x2

   1       0     0  
   1       0     1
   1       1     0
   1       1     1
   2       0     0
   2       0     1
   2       1     0
   2       1     1
   3       0     0  
   3       0     1
   3       1     0
   3       1     1
   4       0     0  
   4       0     1
   4       1     0
   4       1     1", 
header=TRUE)
```

and

```
short <- read.table(text = "
  id_type   y1   y2    

   1       5     6    
   1       5     5    
   2       7     9", 
     header=TRUE)
```

In practice, what I am trying to obtain is:

```
 id_type   x1   x2    

  1       0     0  
  1       0     1
  1       1     0
  1       1     1
  2       0     0  
  2       0     1
  2       1     0
  2       1     1
```

I have tried to use `out <- long[long[,"id_type"]==short[,"id_type"], ]`, but it is clearly wrong. How would you proceed? Thanks

Comment: +1 for the reproducible example and "showing your work"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `%in%`:

```
out <- long[long$id_type %in% short$id_type, ]
```

Look at `?"%in%"`.

Comment: For the sake of clearness, I separated the additional but different question in a brand new post, [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14441028/selecting-rows-according-to-all-covariates-combinations-of-a-different-dataframe).

Answer (score 2):

You where missing `%in%`:

```
> long[long$id_type %in% unique(short$id_type),]
  id_type x1 x2
1       1  0  0                                                             
2       1  0  1                                                             
3       1  1  0                                                             
4       1  1  1                                                             
5       2  0  0                                                             
6       2  0  1                                                             
7       2  1  0                                                             
8       2  1  1
```